# Mac OS X hard drive not mounted from BootCamp

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, macbook, boot-camp

I recently use MacBook White (Mid-2010) that has Windows 7 installed thru BootCamp. From that Windows, I can access Mac OS X hard drive with read-only attributes. Then I decided to upgrade to a MacBook Air (Early-2014), install Windows 8.1 thru BootCamp also. But from that I can’t see my Mac OS X hard drive from my Windows (MyComputer).

Does BootCamp currently not fully supported Windows 8.1? My drivers from Windows are all working fine except that Mac OS X hard drive is not mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp does not install a HFS+ driver. Hence, you cannot read the Mac partition from any Windows install by default. To do so, you would need to install a driver, e.g. something like Paragon's HFS+ for Windows.

Without the HFS+ driver, the data cannot be read. This applies the same for mounting "apple" usb backup disks under normal windows installs too.

That said, *there is a danger*, if you enable HFS+, some caution should be taken, as often Bootcamp runs a hybrid MBR/GPT partition scheme, which becomes very vulnerable.

Comment: BootCamp driver itself has its capability. It was based on my experience on my older Mac. I don't know why now, in my newer Mac, I cannot read or mount the Mac OS HD. I reinstalled my Windows twice and still no luck. I think BootCamp driver for models included MacBook Air (Early-2014) does not support it.